# Proper Ventilation of a Wet Crawlspace

Tags: ventilation, crawlspace, bedroom

I moved into a renal house and afterward noticed my closet smells musty and damp. Ventilation of the crawl space under an exterior concrete stair is provided by a single screened vent on the exterior wall and a perforated panel into my closet. It seems obvious that crawlspace vents should not be in the wall of habitable space.  Where can I find this in the California Building Code?

Comment: I vaguely recall something in the IRC requiring ventilation to be accessible or controllable. There it is. https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2015/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2015_Pt03_Ch03_SecR303.1: "Natural ventilation shall be through windows, skylights, doors, louvers or other approved openings to the outdoor air. Such openings shall be provided with ready access or shall otherwise be readily controllable by the building occupants." Anybody have an IRC Commentary to check this out?

Comment: I'd buy a sheet of poster board and a roll of duct tape.

Comment: @SteveSh  Can make an answer out of this.

Comment: @crip659 - Took your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to mount a small fan in either the closet opening (and blowing into the crawl space), or in the vent on the exterior wall (blowing outward). This will keep crawl space air from migrating into your living area, and should help with any moisture in your crawl space.

If you make this temporary installation, you shouldn't run afoul of your rental agreement.

Think of this as a small step into turning your crawl space into conditioned space.